# The web service execution doesn't work in HTML

Tags: javascript

I am trying to test an exemple of consuming a web service (SOAP) in HTML and JavaScript through this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function soap() {

        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open('POST', 'http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx', true);


var sr =
       '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
       '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">'+
       '<soapenv:Header/>'+
        '<soapenv:Body>'+
        '<web:ConversionRate>'+
     '<web:FromCurrency>EUR</web:FromCurrency>'+
     '<web:ToCurrency>TND</web:ToCurrency>'+
        '</web:ConversionRate>'+
        '</soapenv:Body>'+
        '</soapenv:Envelope>';

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {

                    alert('done use firebug to see response');
                }
            }
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 0) {
                alert('open() has not been called yet');
            }

            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 1) {
                alert('send() has not been called yet');
            }

            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 2) {
                alert('send() has been called, ...');
            }

            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 3) {
                alert('Interactive - Downloading');
            }
            else
            alert('Consuming Error');
        }
        // Send the POST request
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
        xmlhttp.send(sr);
        // send request
        // ...
    }
</script>
```

The problem is that nothing is shown (I talk about the differents alerts), and the "onreadystatechange" function is not executed!

I didn't figure out the reason?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You cannot send cross-domain AJAX requests unless the foreign server sends CORS headers. Take a look in the dev console, it will show you an error.

Comment: Do you ever call that function?

Comment: Did you actually call the soap() function? When I run it, I get two alerts: "send() has been called, ..." and "Consuming Error". Also a valid comment about cross-domain requests.

Comment: Yes I have already called the soap() function with the form: <body> <form> <input type="button" value="send" onclick="soap();"/> </form> </body> But no results! By the way, there is no error message in the IDE console (I use Tizen IDE)

Comment: Even with CORS header, most browsers will not allow CORS request when the page is served from disk. You need to serve the page on a server. Some browsers go even further and refuse to allow CORS request if the server is served from localhost or 127.0.0.1 so you need to give it a domain name (usually by editing your hosts file)